# Python: How to pass multiple x, y coordinates from a df into a function at once?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, input, parameters

I have a df containing x, y coordinates that looks like this:

```
x    y
280  230
230  247
219  255
209  270
203  290
199  313
198  336
204  365
208  372
220  392
253  429
281  448
...  ...
```

The function that I created must take in 4 x coordinates and 4 corresponding y coordinates at a time, however I don't know how to iterate through a df and pass 4 rows of data at a time. Here is an example of my function call at the moment:

```
my_function(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy)
```

The function call doesn't have to be this way, I just need to be able to access all 4 x and y coordinates.

How would I go about passing the data into my function?

**Edit**: Just to clarify, the rows need to be passed in on a rolling basis, so I would like to call `my_function(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4)` and then `my_function(x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5)` and so on...

Comment: You can use `.assign` Example `dataf.assign(results = lambda df: function(4 * df['x'], df[y]))`

Answer (score 0):

`Rolling` over multiple columns in `pandas` is quite tricky, because it only supports single column aggregations. But you can `roll` over one column and slice the same rows out of multiple columns of you dataframe. Also rolling `apply` must return one single number. So, a rolling solution could be

```
def my_function(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy):
    return ax + ay + bx + by + cx + cy + dx + dy

df['result'] = df.rolling(4, min_periods=4).x.apply(
    lambda x: my_function(*df.loc[x.index, ['x','y']].to_numpy().ravel()))
df
```

Output

```
      x    y  result
0   280  230     NaN
1   230  247     NaN
2   219  255     NaN
3   209  270  1940.0
4   203  290  1923.0
5   199  313  1958.0
6   198  336  2018.0
7   204  365  2108.0
8   208  372  2195.0
9   220  392  2295.0
10  253  429  2443.0
11  281  448  2603.0
```

---

Assuming you want to pass consecutive slices of rows to your function you can group every 4 rows and flatten the dataframe to get the shape you need.

```
def my_function(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy):
    return f'ax={ax}, ay={ay}, bx={bx}, by={by}, cx={cx}, cy={cy}, dx={dx}, dy={dy}'

df.groupby(df.index//4).apply(lambda x: my_function(*x.to_numpy().ravel()))
```

Output

```
0    ax=280, ay=230, bx=230, by=247, cx=219, cy=255...
1    ax=203, ay=290, bx=199, by=313, cx=198, cy=336...
2    ax=208, ay=372, bx=220, by=392, cx=253, cy=429...
dtype: object
```

Dataframe used in this example

```
import pandas as pd
import io

t = '''
x    y
280  230
230  247
219  255
209  270
203  290
199  313
198  336
204  365
208  372
220  392
253  429
281  448'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
df
```

Output

```
      x    y
0   280  230
1   230  247
2   219  255
3   209  270
4   203  290
5   199  313
6   198  336
7   204  365
8   208  372
9   220  392
10  253  429
11  281  448
```

Comment: I have updated my post to clarify that the input need to come on a rolling basis, so we'll have my_function(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) and then my_function(x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5), then my function(x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, y6), etc. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @FirstNameLastName - I added a rolling solution

Comment: Your rolling solution was exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom grouper using `np.arange(len(df))//4` to make groups of 4.

##### to get the function output back in the dataframe:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//4).apply(lambda g: g.values.flatten())
```

output:

```
0    [280, 230, 230, 247, 219, 255, 209, 270]
1    [203, 290, 199, 313, 198, 336, 204, 365]
2    [208, 372, 220, 392, 253, 429, 281, 448]
dtype: object
```

##### to apply a function per group and get the result outside of the dataframe:

```
for name, g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//4):
    print(f'group: {name}')
    print(g.values.flatten()) # replace print here with your function
```

output:

```
group: 0
[280 230 230 247 219 255 209 270]
group: 1
[203 290 199 313 198 336 204 365]
group: 2
[208 372 220 392 253 429 281 448]
```